# Total size of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, size

I'm trying to manipulate a list into a matrix and for some reason it's not working...

```
    import numpy as np

    dcd=np.load('dcd_250.npy')
    #4. write the dcd into an array
    print 'Length of dcd', len(dcd)

    al_gtps = np.array(dcd).reshape(250000,5416)            # reshape(SNP no, ind no)
    print 'Size of al_gtps', al_gtps.size                                                 

    gtps_T=al_gtps.T

    print 'Size of gtps_T', gtps_T.size

    allelic_gtps=[]
    check=[]
    #5. turn into strings
    for k in gtps_T:
        check=k
        allelic_gtps.append("%s" % ' '.join(map(str,k)))

    print 'Length of allelic_gtps', len(allelic_gtps)


    together=[]
    for each in allelic_gtps:
        for ch in each:
            if ch!=' ':
                together.append(ch)
        else:
             pass

    matrix=np.array(together).reshape(5416,500000)

    np.save('matrix.npy', matrix)
```

The length of the array is as it should be:

```
Length of dcd 1354000000
Size of al_gtps 1354000000
Size of gtps_T 1354000000
Length of allelic_gtps 5416
Length of together 2708000000
```

My final matrix should have 5416 rows with 500 000 column each. Which gives 2 708 000 000, and that's what I have in "together". However, I'm getting a following error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "p3_gtp_format.py", line 51, in <module>
    matrix=np.array(together).reshape(5416,500000)
    ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

This should not be a matter of memory, as I'm working on a large memory machine. This same script worked on smaller datasets, where the size of matrix was 5416 rows and 200 000 columns. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you do it in 2 steps.  `temp = np.array(together); print temp.shape; matrix = temp.reshape(5416,500000)`

Comment: That for loop will remove any spaces in the `together` array. You print `Length of together 2708000000`- where is that `print` statement in your code?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted it while writing this question. Print 'Length of together' goes just before the matrix line.